# The file "spng.dll" is not founded in my Visual Studio's project and i get an error

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2022

I am using the libspng library in C++ and, with the library and the .h installed, it gives me an error and sends me this message:[The error]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/4am31.png)

Please, I need your help.

I have searched many sites on the internet and there is nothing that works. If you need any capture, tell me.

Comment: Search your hard drive for the `spng.dll`.  If found, this is the path you need to supply to compiler.  Otherwise, reinstall `libspng` library.  Do you need to build the library?  Did you tell the compiler the *correct* library to use, like `libspng.dll`?

Comment: The dll needs to be somewhere on your path or in the application directory

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's a runtime error not a compiler error

Comment: You don't tell the compiler anything. It has already worked fine. The dll needs to be somewhere on your path or in the application directory as @AlanBirtles says.

Comment: @AlanBirtles and how do I solve that?

Comment: How do I indicate where the dll is?

Comment: "How do I indicate where the dll is" You can to that by (1) modifying your PATH environment variable **or** (2) by copying the dll to one of the directories that are already listed in PATH **or** (3) by copying the dll to the directory where your application is. I recommend (3).

Comment: https://imgur.com/SO2fsTe

Comment: No, the application is the .exe file.

Comment: Copy the file in that picture you just posted to the same folder as your .exe file for your application.

Comment: Update: I have placed the dll where the solution is and it has worked. He also asked me for the zlibd one and I placed it. now open. Thank you all!!!

Comment: The following Microsoft document describes how your OS finds dlls and what you as a programmer need to do to help the OS be successful in its search: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps)